# Samba testparam command not found

Tags: linux, windows, sharing, samba, file-sharing

There is a utility, testparam, used to check if smb.conf is valid at /etc/samba/smb.conf after adding a Samba share.
However, trying to set up a new share I just made, my Linux server does recognize command "testparam."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try 'testparm'. Hope this helps :-P

Comment: Thanks! Glad I'm not the only one that got stuck on this.